# Indexing a column in HAVING clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, having

I got a table with over 12 columns. This is the mysql query used to retrive the latest 7 records

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id IN(12,10,7,1) HAVING continent IN('Europe','America','Australia') AND NOT MATCH(weather) AGAINST('+"[blues]"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) || continent = 'Asia' AND MATCH(weather) AGAINST('+"[purples]"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY tb_id DESC LIMIT 7`

Total rows are more than `5 million` and `user_id` is an indexed column with `tb_id` being the `PRIMARY KEY`. When i use the `EXPLAIN` in front of `SELECT`. MySQL tells that it will read over 400 thousand records from a total of 5 million.

So should I index continent column or it won't help in this case?

Here is the EXPLAIN result

`id = 1; select_type = SIMPLE; table = data; possible_keys = user_id; key = user_id; ref = NULL; rows = 582; Extra = Using where, Using filesort`

Comment: Why is this in the HAVING clause?

Comment: Is the `HAVING` clause a remainder of a `GROUP BY` clause that was later removed? Is `||` intended to be a boolean OR or a string concatenation? Is `continent` indexed? And you forgot to post the explain plan.

Comment: continent is not indexed. Thats what i want to know. And HAVING is an extension to GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your query is probably wrong. When you use `OR` mixed with `AND` in where or having clause or anywhere, you should use parantheses.

Second, using HAVING in your case doesn't make sense and the optimizer will most likely convert it to a WHERE clause.

The difference between the two is, that `WHERE` is applied when determining which rows to select. `HAVING` is applied on the result set. So, if the optimizer wouldn't do a good job, you would first get (almost) all rows, then filter those. When you put it all in the `WHERE` clause, you get only the relevant rows. `HAVING` (almost) only makes sense when you are using `GROUP BY`.

So, you better write your query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE user_id IN(12,10,7,1) AND
(
(
continent IN('Europe','America','Australia') 
AND NOT MATCH(weather) AGAINST('+"[blues]"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
)
OR 
(
continent = 'Asia' 
AND MATCH(weather) AGAINST('+"[purples]"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
)
)
ORDER BY tb_id DESC LIMIT 7
```

To answer your question about the index, post the result of the explain and the create statements of your table `data`.

Comment: Thanks @tomboom. Here is the result of explain


`id = 1
select_type = SIMPLE
table = data
possible_keys = user_id
key = user_id
ref = NULL
rows = 582
Extra = Using where, Using filesort`

Comment: Also for better readability you can end the statement with `\G` instead of `;`. Then the columns become rows and it's easier to post.

Comment: @RayZ Also don't forget to do `SHOW CREATE TABLE data` and post the result, please.

Comment: Your explain plan says, that the index on user_id is already used. what you can try (apart from adding another index on continent) is a compound index over two columns (user_id, continent).

Comment: On localhost, i am able to fetch 582 rows in undex 20 milliseconds. So i don't believe that adding an index on continent would help. And thanks again @tomboom. U really hepled me eliminate `HAVING` from my query.